# I cannot delete a file with python

Tags: python, shutil

First off I am not too familiar with python and still currently learning also its my first time ever posting here so sorry if I am mess up with some details.

I am running experiments, and need to run multiple replicates. The issue arises when I need to start a new set of replicates, the program moves the already run experiments into a new folder and is then suppose to start the new replicates. However, what happens only on the last experiment, the environment.cfg folder is not transferred and the program crashes.

```
from os import listdir,chdir
import subprocess
from random import randrange,sample
from shutil import copy,copytree,rmtree
from os import mkdir,remove
import csv
import time
import shutil

test = input("Is this a test? (y/n)")
if test == "y":
    text = input("What are you testing?")
    testdoc=open("Testing Documentation.txt","a")
    testdoc.write(text)
elif test != "y" and test != "n":
    print("Please type in y or n")
    test = input("Is this a test? (y/n)")
    
expnum = int(input("Number of Experiments: "))
exptype = int(input("Which experiment do you want to run? (1/2)"))
repnum= int(input("How many replicates do you want?"))
print(f"You want {repnum} replicates, each replicate will contain {expnum} for a total of {repnum*expnum}")
confirm = input("Is this correct? (y/n)")

if confirm == "y":
    for rep in range(repnum):
        
        if exptype == 1:
            for ex in range (expnum):
                num= ex + 1   
                mkdir('experiment_'+str(num)) #create a directory named cdir
                copy('./default_files/environment.cfg','./experiment_'+str(num)+'/environment.cfg') #copy one file from one place to another
        
                #WSIZE
                env_file = open('./experiment_'+str(num)+'/environment.cfg','r')
                env_file_content = []
                for i in env_file:
                    env_file_content.append(i.split(' '))
        
                #env_file_content = [['a','b'],['c','d']]
                #access first line: env_file_content[0] ; note that index in python start from 0
                #access first element in second line: env_file_content[1][0] ; note that index in python start from 0
        
                n = num #number of resources
                var0 = '100' #resource inflow
                var1 = '0.01' #resource outflow
                var3 = '1' # The minimum amount of resource required
                reactiontype = ['not','nand','and','orn','or','andn','nor','xor','equ']
                reward = ["1.0","1.0","2.0","2.0","4.0","4.0","8.0","8.0","16.0"]
        
        
                #n = sample(range(10),1)[0]
        
                out = open('./experiment_'+str(num)+'/environment.cfg','w')
                for i in range(n):
                    out.write('RESOURCE res'+str(i)+':inflow='+var0+':outflow='+var1+'\n')
        
                sc=0
                for i in range(n):
                    out.write('REACTION reaction'+str(i)+' '+reactiontype[sc]+' process:resource=res'+str(i)+':value='+reward[sc]+':min='+var3+   '\n')
                    sc+=1
                    if sc==len(reactiontype):
                        sc = 0 
                out.close()
            
                ##RUN Avida from python
                copy('./experiment_' + str(num) + '/environment.cfg', './')
                print("starting experiment_" + str(num))
                
                proc = subprocess.Popen(['./avida'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
                
                # Wait for the subprocess to finish
                output, error = proc.communicate()
                
                # Close the subprocess
                proc.terminate()
                
                shutil.move('./data','./experiment_' +str(num))
                #copytree('./data', './experiment_' + str(num) + '/data')
                #rmtree('./data')
                remove('./environment.cfg')

        replicatenum = rep + 1
        mkdir('replicate_'+str(replicatenum)) #create a directory named replicate_
        for repl in range(expnum):
            numb = repl + 1  
            source = './experiment_'+str(numb)
            dest = './replicate_' + str(replicatenum) + '/experiment_' + str(numb)
            shutil.move(source, dest)
```

I tried renaming the folder, however that also failed. The issue seems only to arise when the program is running as taking the same code after the program has crashed, will cause no problems.

Comment: what error does the program print in the console when it crashes? that's the key that will tell you why the error happens and where.

Comment: It give no error, it just closes with no warning. Is there somehow I can get it to give a error?

Comment: If it doesn't give any error how do you know it crashes? Also you are doing `env_file = open(...)` but you never close this file. Have you debugged your file line by line and see where does it not do what you expect to do?

Comment: Because, it should run the next set of replicates and never starts them. Thanks for also pointing that issue out, I think that might be it!!

Comment: you shouldn't use a bae open. use `with open(...)` instead. It will handle automatically the closing of the file